# Compiling protocol buffers:Missing output directives

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I tried to compile proto(Ubuntu 18.04)

```
protoc — go_out=. test.proto 
Missing output directives.
```

My env

```
go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/miki/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/miki/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8"
GCCGO="/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gccgo-8"
CC="x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8"
CXX="x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-8"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build089604877=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -funwind-tables"
```

protoc-gen-go is in my bin

```
~/go/bin$ ls
gocode  gopkgs  goreturns  protoc-gen-go
```

I edited my bashrc

```
echo $PATH
/home/miki/go/bin
```

Strugle with the same thing again.

How to set ouput directives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your original command has a space between the `--` and `go_out=.`?

Answer (score 1):

Write your command like this:

```
protoc --go_out=. test.proto
```

If you need it for a gRPC server:

```
protoc --go-grpc_out=. test.proto
```

for more details, I wanna tell you this part *--go_out=.* is related to

```
option go_package="/<folder_name>";
```

that you wrote in your *.proto* file and both are used to determine the output address.